# How to remove all the workspaces created by Visual Studio Code at once?

Tags: visual-studio-code, microsoft

I want to remove all the workspaces created by Visual Studio Code. It's taking a lot of spaces. I searched the net but found that I have to go to each workspace I created and remove them one by one.

But Can I delete them all at once by removing all the folders under `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`, that is by deleting all the folders in the image attached here [The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBnNO.png).

And also Can I delete these folders without any harm (its taking nearly 1 GB)?

Comment: If you delete your workspaces it means whatever is contained within those folders will be deleted. What harm specifically are you worried about?

Comment: @Ramhound I am worried about, deleting this won't create problems in my preexisting codes. So, according to you it won't create any problems right ?

Comment: If you delete your workspaces, your previous code contained in those workspaces would be presumably deleted.  So you would want to backup and/or NOT delete those workspaces that you want to keep.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without any harm". What harm?

Comment: with out any changes in my the working code or extension or VS Code as a whole

Comment: @Ramhound no it does not show any harm. Feel free to delete them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its safe to delete.

Just Delete all the folders in the `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage`.

You can also delete everything in (to make VS Code a little faster) :

- `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\Cache`
- `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\CacheData`

Comment: Does deleting workspaces lose code you've written in those workspaces and not saved?

Comment: no it does not show any harm. Feel free to delete them